# CBCentralManagerDelegate didRetrievePeripherals not found

Tags: swift, macos-sierra, cbcentralmanager

I am trying to implement Apple's sample code written in Objective-C in Swift on MacOS with Deployment target 10.12. The sample can be found here for reference: [Heart Rate Monitor](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/HeartRateMonitor/Introduction/Intro.html)

On implementation, I came across an issue where the CentralManager: didRetrievePeripherals callback is not implementable. I have checked both the CBCentralManagerDelegate and CBPheripheralDelegate protocols that my ViewController implements and none of them contain such a method. The only methods I can find are:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?)
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral)
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any])
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?)
```

I am not quite sure what is going wrong here. I checked Apple's Objective-C version and went through both delegates implemented there but don't see anything in the protocol definitions anything that says that I can implement the following function:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrievePeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals
{
    ...
}
```

But they have implemented this under the set of CBCentralManagerDelegates and project builds without issue. How is this possible?

My implementation for reference is as follows:

```
import Cocoa
import CoreBluetooth
import QuartzCore

class ViewController: NSViewController, CBPeripheralDelegate, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    var manager: CBCentralManager?
    var peripheral: CBPeripheral?
    var autoconnect = true
    let arrayController: NSArrayController = NSArrayController()
    var heartRateMonitors = NSMutableArray()
    let scanSheet: NSWindow = NSWindow()

    //MARK: IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var connectButton: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var indicatorButton: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressIndicator: NSProgressIndicator!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


        manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        if autoconnect {
            startScan()
        }
    }
...
}
```

Thank you

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/iOS90APIDiffs/Objective-C/CoreBluetooth.html: Removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Apple changelog](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/iOS90APIDiffs/Swift/CoreBluetooth.html) we can get that `centralManager: didRetrievePeripherals` method was removed in iOS 9. So if you are using xcode with latest SKD this method is not included in it.

Comment: thank you. Can you direct me to the alternatives that Apple suggests or any reasoning why they deprecated this so I can figure out how to work without it

Comment: You can follow raywenderlich blog post here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/177848/core-bluetooth-tutorial-for-ios-heart-rate-monitor

Comment: yes.. but that's an iOS tutorial. Are both implementations same?

Comment: mac os and iOS using same Core Bluetooth SDK, so their implementation of it delegates should be the same. You can refer to raywenderlich tutorial as to the reference of how to setup bluetooth, however other things, like showing results on UITableVIew/NSTableView, will be different